# Noun or best suggestion to describe the accumulation of interaction (pos/neg) between two people

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm looking for a noun preferably that I can best describe as:

The opinion someone has of you - due to the actions which have occurred between the two of you.

For example - When two people first meet, there are hundreds of 'ratings' piling up with each interaction between them. Person A might tell a crude joke not knowing Person B finds such humor as barbaric. This event then causes a 60% negative effect - as opposed to exercising bad sarcasm which would only have a 10% negative effect. I'm also thinking in terms of an RPG dashboard context. Hopefully that gives you a bit more to go on. The sum of these actions should constitute a single word. I'm trying to find that word. Thanks for the help.

---- Edit

I'm building an interface for an RPG project. The word has to literally describe the numeric value 0% = Pure hatred guts TO 100% = Soul Mates. Each action chosen by the player has a multiplier and I guess percentage of effect on the person they encounter. So I need one word to describe (Unisex) that value between the player and the NPC (AI).

Comment: Overall _impression_?

Comment: Hmm, that's pretty good but still not quite what I'm looking for in this case. I keep thinking "Social Alignment" or something along those lines. But Overall impression is dead on the path to the word I'm searching for.

Comment: It's quite broad, but would *relationship* fit ?

Comment: Would **history** work?

Comment: *Estimation*, perhaps, as in "My estimation of James is that he is a splendid fellow."

Comment: Relationship is good too - but there is another word buried in my mind that I saw on one of those really in depth RPG games. I'm hoping someone can help me find it.

Comment: No history and Estimation are not intuitive enough for the context. Maybe it would help if you told me what was too broad. I could elaborate a bit more for you. I'm just kind of reaching as it is already.

Comment: Does that help you guys any?

Comment: Perception of, opinion of, take on and judgement of are all possibilities. You could use 'informed' with 'opinion' at least.

Comment: I hate the idea of leaving an "of" hanging off there though. But yes, they are in the ballpark of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Maybe _affinity_ ? Try looking on [here](http://www.thesaurus.com) for synonyms of any of the words we've mentioned so far, it might help.

Comment: reputation       .. .

Comment: It's a shame *copacetic* hasn't been more productive. *Copacance* would seem about right.

Comment: I suggest ***compatibility*** for the game attribute, but I like ***history*** as the accumulation of interactions between two people generally.

Comment: title asks for *"**my take** on the situation"* - In *The Sims*, it's called 'relationship'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps "**affinity**" would serve.  This sense of the word is defined by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affinity) as

> a feeling of closeness and understanding that someone has for another
>   person because of their similar qualities, ideas, or interests

Comment: Oops, didn't expand the comments section to notice that @Irhala had already mentioned this.  Apologies.  Nevertheless, I'll leave this in place as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Chemistry**

> The complex emotional or psychological interaction between people.
>   *Most baseball men subscribe to familiar truisms about talent, character, and the chemistry of winning teams*.
>   — [OD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chemistry)

FIFA 17 on Xbox/PS has a numerical chemistry rating which seems similar to what was described in question.

> There are two types of Chemistry in FIFA Ultimate Team, which make up an overall Chemistry rating, plus the Chemistry Style modifiers which affect how they work. Here are the key terms:
>
> 1. **Individual Player Chemistry**- Rated out of 10 for each player.
> 2. **Chemistry** - Rated out of 100 for the entire team.
> 3. **Overall Chemistry** - This is a hidden number, which comes from a combination of Individual Player Chemistry and Team Chemistry. A high Overall Chemistry will increase player attributes; a low Overall Chemistry will actually decrease them.
>
> [image]
>
> —  [Eurogamer.net](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2016-10-14-fifa-17-fut-chemistry-explained-how-to-increase-chemistry-get-100-team-chemistry-and-max-individual-chemistry)

Answer (score 1):

***History***

I've known my acquaintance Danny since we were kids.  He was a brat, I've never really forgiven him for putting bleach on my hair in 5th grade.  But somehow he became friends with my sister, their kids are friends, he brought my mom casseroles when she was laid up fighting cancer.  He tells tasteless jokes and I kicked hm out of my house for a racist comment at the holidays one year, but he works hard to improve the schools in poor neighborhoods in our city.  I can say this, we have a lot of ***history*** between us.

Colloquial meaning related to these formal definitions:

[history at dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/history) meaning 3:  the aggregate of past events

[history at M-W.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/history) meaning 4: an established record

Answer (score 0):

You should consider ***likemindedness/like-mindedness***. A score of 0% would imply that they are are not at all *likeminded* whereas 100% would imply that they are, well, totally *likeminded*.

Also, ***compatibility*** (synonymous with *likemindedness*) may work.

ODO:

> **[like-mindedness](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/like-mindedness)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> *See **like-minded***
>
> ‘I've got a great, wry sense of humor and a few good friends of
>   like-mindedness.’
>
> **[like-minded](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/like-minded)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> *Having similar tastes or opinions.*
>   ‘a small group of like-minded friends’
>
> ‘Blogging is the medium that lets us communicate with like-minded
>   people.’
>   ‘The company of other like-minded people adds to their
>   enjoyment and enhances the feeling of well being.’
>
> **[compatibility](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/compatibility)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1.1** A feeling of sympathy and friendship; **like-mindedness**:
>   ‘they felt the bond of true compatibility’

Wiktionary:

> *Noun*
>   **[likemindedness](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/likemindedness)** ‎(uncountable)
>
> *Alternative spelling of **like-mindedness***